# Trying to run a python script using crontab, it's throwing a syntax issue that doesn't come up anywhere else I run it

Tags: python, pandas, cron

```
    X_df[str(val)+'sma'] = X_df['Close'].rolling(f'{val}D').mean()   # using the pandas rolling function to calculate mean values over each desired SMA value
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

For some context this is using the rolling function taking in val of 7, 30 and 60 before the D, which gives me an average over those time frames. It appears the error indicator is fixed under the last ' after the D.

I'm getting this error in my crontab mail every time it attempts to run my script.
I have run the script directly from the command line and also in a jupyter notebook with no issues, I cannot figure out why this issue is popping up now.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing this? Or tips as to where I may be able to look?

Comment: The LIKELY cause here is that your crontab's path is causing your code to be executed in a different version of Python, and that version is old, before f-strings were introduced.  You might try including the full path to Python in your crontab entry or your she-bang #! line.

Comment: It's Python 3 code. Maybe cron is trying to run it as Python 2?
Specify version of Python and I hope it'll be ok.

Comment: When I feed that code to python2 I get that same error message: "`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`". Showing the entire script you're running (or a reduced one that gives the same error) would be very helpful. My guess is that you have `#!/usr/bin/env python` and the reduced `$PATH` used by crontab is giving you a Python2 interpreter. Try `#!/usr/bin/env python3` or `#!/full/path/to/python3`.

Comment: check your crontab file and python path in it

Answer (score 0):

As some comments said, perhaps crontab is using the wrong version of the Python interpreter. Instead of relying on shebang line, usually I do something like this to be sure:

```
*/10  *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/python3 /root/bin/hello.py
```

so that you can be 100% certain that `/usr/bin/python3` is called to run the Python script.

Answer (score 0):

It was definitely the wrong version.

I was calling on python in the `/usr/bin/env/python` instead of from the correct place for using Anaconda `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`.

Thanks for your help.

*Still trying to figure out how to reward the first comment as correct.*